# How to trigger the processing of new values added to a vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store that stores entries:

```
const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      entries: [
        {
          id: 1,
          date-of-birth: "2020-10-15T14:48:00.000Z",
          name: "Tom",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

I get these entries by using a getter in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  entries() {
    var entries = this.$store.getters.entries;
  }
}
```

For some reason, I want to always output the newest `date-of-birth` in the store. Initially, I was able to do this in two ways:

- By creating an additional computed property `newest_date-of-birth`
- By simply adding a new `data` variable `newest_date-of-birth` that gets set within (e.g.) the `beforeMounted` hook.

However, when I add a new entry (through the app), both these methods do not update `newest_date-of-birth` as only the computed property `entries` is triggered.

I tried to solve this in two approaches:

- When I try to update `newest_date-of-birth` within the computed
  property `entries`, I get advised not to do this as it seems to be
  bad practise (no-side-effects-in-computed-properties).
- Also `watch`ing over computed property `entries` does not work;
  apparently this only works for data variables.

So my question is: How do I update `newest_date-of-birth` after a value is added to (or removed from, for that matter) the store?

Thanks!

Comment: You are only showing the `state` property of your vuex object. I assume you are also using the `mutation` property to set internal values. If so, all you have to do if set multiple states on a single mutation and both of them will update in your `computed` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only showing the `state` property of your vuex object. I assume you are also using the `mutation` property to set internal values.

If so, all you have to do is set multiple states on a single mutation and both of them will update in your `computed` values, like this:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    entries: []
    lastEntrie: null
  },
  mutations: {
    addEntrie (state, entrie) {
      state.entries.push(entrie);
      state.lastEntrie = entrie;
    }
  }
})
```

Then, in your `computed` values:

```js
computed: {
  myEntries () {
    return this.$store.state.entries
  }
  theLastEntrie () {
    return this.$store.state.lastEntrie
  }
}
```

Comment: As it is not exactly the newest entry I want to save in the variable, but rather the newest date among all saved entries (it could be that the date from a newly added entry is not the newest (or youngest)), I need to do this calculation (1) in the beginning and (2) after every change in the state (add/update /remove entry). Can your solution be adapted to solve this? (I see that I expanded my question with this comment - sorry for that and thanks a lot for your help!!)

Comment: the `addEntrie` property is a function, you can do any synchronous operation in there. So you can interact the hole `state.entries` and search for the last one.

Comment: The note that it is just a function did it! I now call the mutation with `store.commit()` as mentioned here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/call-a-vuex-mutation-at-beginning-of-instance/40507